# Why var=""; [ -n $var ] && echo T || echo F returns F?

Tags: bash

I found the following command:

```
var=""; [ -n $var ] && echo T || echo F
```

This command returns F.
In my understanding, $var is null so the command should return T.

I also checked this:

```
[ -n "" ] && echo T || echo F
```

This returns T as I expected.

I can not understand why

```
[ -n "" ] && echo T || echo F
```

returns T but

```
var="" [ -n $var ] && echo T || echo F
```

returns F?

I checked them on CentOS6.4 bash4.1.2

Comment: `var=""; [ -n $var ] && echo T || echo F` prints `T`

Comment: Use the extension (available in bash, ksh, zsh and others) `[[ -n $var ]]` and you get different parse rules preventing string-splitting, and thus avoiding this problem. If you're going to use the old-style POSIX `[` command, you need to use the same caution you'd use with any other command -- because it's a **command** (even if a built-in one), not **syntax**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary: *always* quote your parameter expansions unless you know why it should not be. Use `[ -n "$var" ]` instead.

---

When unquoted,

```
[ -n $var ]
```

expands to

```
[ -n ]
```

that is, the empty string is removed from the input and `bash` is left with a one-argument call to `[`, which means the command returns true if the argument is non-empty. `-n` here is not an operator; it is simply a non-empty string.

You need to quote the parameter expansion so that

```
[ -n "$var" ]
```

expands to

```
[ -n "" ]
```

which is a two-argument call to `[`, which will do as you expect: test if the second argument has non-zero length.

Answer (score 2):

This difference in output in case when you use a variable is that you don't quote the variable.

When you say:

```
[ -n $var ] && echo T || echo F
```

the shell reads it as:

```
'[' -n ']'
```

and returns `T`.  This case is equivalent to saying `[ foo ]` which would always be true.

On the other hand, when you say:

```
[ -n "" ] && echo T || echo F
```

the shell would read it as:

```
'[' -n '' ']'
```

and return `F`.